# Passing more than one view to template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a page that should show an event and the presentations of this event. In my code they are not related (I still have to fix that). On the home page, which receives the event and the lectures, the view is like this:

**views.py**

```
class EventoView(ListView):
    model = Evento
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'evento_list'
    queryset = Evento.objects.all().order_by('-data')[:1]

class RegistroView(ListView):
    model = Registro
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'registro_list'
    queryset = Registro.objects.all()
```

The problem is that I can only pass the Event object, the object of Registration, which show lectures Indexed must also be passed, however, only accepts a Django view for url.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', EventoView.as_view(), name='home'), #I can't pass two views
    url(r'^cadastro/', CriarRegistroView.as_view(), name='cadastro'),
    url(r'^contato/', CriarContatoView.as_view(), name='contato'),
    url(r'^sobre/', SobreView.as_view(), name='sobre'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you can [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.list.ListView) `ListView.get_context_data`

```
class RegistroView(ListView):

    model = Evento

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RegistroListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['registros'] = Registro.objects.all()
        context['eventos'] = Evento.objects.all().order_by('-data')[:1]            
        return context
```

I don't have experience with `ListViews` so i don't know if i am using it as it is supposed to be used, or not

Comment: That is the intended purpose of the `get_context_data`. You are not butchering the `ListView` by doing this.